# history.pushState and history.back Logic Errors

Tags: javascript

I have a single page website that has a modal that loads the different "pages" of content. When the modal loads it also changes the url to something like: *domain.tld/#/specific-modal-page* The modal also has a cancel button that people can click to close the modal.

I'm having issues with my `history.pushState(...)` logic.

On the initial page I don't do anything related to the history variable.

If a user clicks something that opens a modal I think use `history.pushState(...)` and then `history.back()` if they close it.

This worked well for me until I started testing out the webpage by directly loading *domain.tld/#/specific-modal-page* . From this page, if I tried to press the cancel button it would stay put and keep the modal open. I'm guessing because there wasn't a page to go back to.

What's the flaw in my logic? How should I approach this?

Comment: What do you mean by “directly loading domain.tld/#/...”? You mean by entering that exact url into the browser and pressing enter?

Comment: By the way, what kind of a singe page website is it, ReactJS or some other?

Comment: @faithfull, yes, like if someone shared the link with someone else to be able to directly load that particular content. The single web page is built with vanilla JavaScript.

Comment: I never did a full vanilla web page, but I think you’ll have to handle the history differently if you want to keep the same functionality.